# Issue with passing id from Laravel api to Select2 script

Tags: laravel, api, jquery-select2

I have strange problem because previously in my app this code was working but now isn't.
I take data from Laravel api via url address:

```
/api/customer/{id}/products
```

to select2 script

```
$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
    ajax: {
    url: '/api/customer/{id}/products',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
      var query = {
        q: params.term,
      }
    return query;
}
```

but Laravel make url address i that way:

```
api/customer/%7Bid%7D/products
```

so, I have %7Bid%7D instead of {id} and I'm looking for solution in google without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character "7B" is { converter to asci, before the ajax request create a var call "url"

i call the route with his name, for give it the name just attach

```
->name('your_name') in the route file
```

and after in url variable i use the route name instead the full url

```
url = '{{ route("your_route_name", ":id") }}';
```

then replace the id placeholder with the id of select

```
url = url.replace(':id', id);
```

finally in ajax request

```
ajax: { 
    url: url, 

    //the rest of ajax request
}
```

Comment: thank you, it's working till `url = url.replace(':id', id);` moment, now I have error `Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined`